# why we use Lagrangian method in SVM?

Tags: svm, lagrange-multipliers

I am wondering why we are using Lagrangian method in SVM? if we have just 3 features and 1000 rows, then objective function would be $w_{1}^{2}+w_{2}^{2}+w_{3}^{2}$ but if we use Lagrangian then we have 1000 variables (Lagrangian multiplier) so why we do that?

Comment: Could you explain how a "Lagrangian multiplier" constitutes a thousand variables?

Comment: we multiply  each row  by a Lagrangian multiplier